# Laravel get model id inside setAttribute

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I have model like this where i want to get a attribute inside SetFooAttribute. but all time $this->getAttribute('id') is empty! is there a way to access id ?

```
class MyModel extends Model
{

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function($model)
        {
            $model->uuid = Uuid::generate(4)->string;
            $model->save();
        });
    }

    public function setFooAttribute($value)
        {
            $this->attributes['foo'] = $value.'-'.$this->getAttribute('id');
        }
```

Comment: In what context are you using `$model->foo = 'somevalue'`? If you use this before the model is created, the ID is not set yet.

Comment: Yes i use it before model is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [getKey()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getKey) method to get the value of the model's primary key. Use it like `$this->getKey()`

Comment: Yes, getKey() works but only when updating model and not on insert. I still need solution to get id on insert.

Comment: You wont know the id until you actually do the insert. If you want to set an attribute based on the id, you need to do the insert first and then update the field

Comment: Regarding to my question your answer is more approximate, so i will make it as accepted. But I solve it by combining your code with @JanWillem code.

Comment: The important part of SO is that you solve your problem and others can learn from all the answers.

Comment: I get the following error: `Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'`.

Answer (score 2):

Then that is the problem, indeed. The primary key usually increments, which means: your database itself sets it, when executing the 'insert' query. So it is never available before creating the model.

One could calculate the next id beforehand, but this is quite dangerous: it could create a conflict, when - for example - two models are created at the same time.

You could combine this operation with the created() event, by removing the `setFooAttribute` method, and inserting a line of code in the created event:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function($model)
    {
        $model->uuid = Uuid::generate(4)->string;
        $model->foo = $model->foo . '-' . $model->id;
        $model->save();
    });
}
```

This will append *-id* to the original `foo` attribute.

Just curious: why would you want to append the id to a column?

Comment: I have a model where status is changed dynamically over some processes. (paid, unpaid, shipped etc..) So i make a log for each status change.

Comment: I used your solution in combination with @phobia82 solution. Thank your very much.