# Laravel Eloquent: get model id from inside getAttribute function?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, accessor, getattribute

I have a model like the following:

```
User extends Authenticatable 
{
   protected $appends = array('role');

   public function getRoleAttribute()
   {
      $role = DB::table('acl_user_has_roles')->where('user_id', $this->id)
                ->value('role');
      return $role;
   }
 }
```

When I try to reference this foo attribute like the following:

```
$user = User::find(1);
unset($user->id);   // This line causes the problem.
echo $user->role;
```

I always get "null" instead of expected "Owner".

What did I miss here?

I am running this in laravel 5.5.43.

In the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712755/laravel-get-model-id-inside-setattribute), getKey() function was mentioned, that didn't work.

The problem is actually caused by something else, as described in the following [medium post](https://medium.com/@lynnlin827/be-careful-to-use-laravel-eloquents-accessors-mutators-and-events-45d820f54b8e).

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention: Laravel 5.5.43.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. Is this actually the code you have or have you simplified it for the question?

Comment: I simplified it for the question. In real code, I use $this->id to query another table from which I always get null results, then finally narrowed the problem down to $this->id insider getAttribute() always return null. Other properties of $user seems to work just fine inside getAttribute functions.

Comment: Could you add your actual code? I've tried you're above code and that appears to be working absolutely fine.

Comment: The problem was narrowed further down to another line. I unset $user->id before echo. It still doesn't make much sense to me though.

Comment: Did you have a user with an id of 1?

Comment: actually no. Code is simplified for the question. I don't see the problem of having a user with id = 1 though. It has to start from somewhere.

Comment: I would suggest trying not to simplify your code too much in future as it can lead to people looking for the wrong issue e.g. if the `unset` had been visible in your question at the beginning it would have been a lot easier to know your issue. Also,  I would suggest adding a relationship for `acl_user_has_roles` and access the `role` value with the relationship instead of using a query.

Comment: Point noted. I just didn't realize that little unset could cause problem so further away.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else runs into the same issue. The problem is caused by another line in the code. I unset $user->id before echo.

The issue is described in detail in the following medium post:

[Be Careful to Use Laravel Eloquent’s Accessors, Mutators And Events](https://medium.com/@lynnlin827/be-careful-to-use-laravel-eloquents-accessors-mutators-and-events-45d820f54b8e)